# What's the cause of the scars on these cherries?

Tags: botany, infectious-diseases

These cherries have some scars. Are they coming from a disease? Is it correct to call them "Cherry scabs"?

Here's the photo: [image: Pic1] - [image: Pic2]

Comment: U think those happened way before the cherrie were ripened, else the lack of acid would have made them rot from exposure, so I don't know why they would split at that stage, considering they usually split from excess rain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they coming from a disease?

No, this appears to be a combination of rain damage and pests. If a disease were present, much more of the cherry would suffer, there would be signs of rotting, and, the damage wouldn't solely be so superficial, as is the case in your posted images.

Consider the next few images which demonstrate the effects that various diseases have on a cherry, and notice how much more detrimental [and different] the impact.

[Bitter Rot *(Colletrotrichum gloeosporioides & C. acutatum)*](http://agris.fao.org/agris-search/search.do?recordID=PL8601135)
[image: Effects of Bit Rot disease on cherry fruit]

[Brown Rot *(Monolinia fructicola)*](https://wiki.bugwood.org/Monilinia_(brown_rot_of_stone_fruit))
[image: Effects of monilia fructigena disease on cherry fruit]

[Alternaria Rot (*Alternaria sp.)*](http://postharvest.tfrec.wsu.edu/pages/J4I1F)
[image]

There are other [equally common] diseases of cherry trees *(Prunus sp.)*, including [cherry spot leaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_leaf_spot), [black knot](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/plum/black-knot-tree-disease.htm), [silver leaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chondrostereum_purpureum), and [PNRSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_necrotic_ringspot_virus), however, in pretty much all of these cases too, there's no modification to the cherry fruit (excluding extreme circumstances, as is the case with spot leaf, I believe).

Instead, as mentioned, one major cause of the damage is rain. **Just before harvest, when the cherry is at it's greatest [and possibly maximum] volume, rain that's absorbed through the surface of the cherry causes the cherry to further enlarge, which ultimately splits the cuticle (skin).** The result is the following:

[image: effects of rain damage on cherry fruit1]

[image: effects of rain damage on cherry fruit2]

For more information on cherry splitting/cracking:

- [Fruit Splitting (Cracking) – What causes it and can we do anything about it?](http://www.rarefruitclub.org.au/Level2/FruitSplits.htm)
- [Fruit Split In Cherries: Learn Why Cherry Fruits Split Open](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/cherry/fruit-split-in-cherries.htm)
- [A Review of Cherry Fruit Cracking](http://extension.oregonstate.edu/umatilla/mf/sites/default/files/WA_State_Cherry_Cracking_Kaiser_Dec_07.pdf)
- [Story: Stone fruit and the summerfruit industry](https://teara.govt.nz/en/video/18797/rain-damages-cherries)
- [Cherry Weather Worries](http://cliffmass.blogspot.com/2016/05/cherry-weather-worries.html)

Given the irregularities of *scarring* on some of the cherries, I also suggest that insects and/or birds scratched/ate away at them. Consider the following images that illustrate the kind of damage that birds & wasps cause when feeding on cherries, and notice the similarities to those in your images.

*bird damage*
[image]

*wasp damage*
[image]

**This, in combination with the rain, is most likely what caused damage to your cherries.**

> Is it correct to call them "Cherry scabs"?

I just call it scarring, and I believe many other people do too. I'm not sure if there's a specific term for fruit damage that's then been "scabbed" over. *If someone knows of a term for this, please provide in a comment and I will supplement my response with it. Thank you*.

---

While continuing to research this topic, specifically when attempting to find *alternative* reasons that could explain this kind of damage, I did ran across [this](http://msue.anr.msu.edu/news/how_should_fruit_growers_respond_to_hail_and_severe_storms) article which talks about *wind damage*, and provides an image that slightly resembles the markings on your cherries. I'm still heavily convinced though that your cherries suffered their damage from rain & pests.

[image: storm damage to cherries]

Comment: This answer has a lot of "beliefs" and "suggestions" - we prefer referenced answers at Biology.SE for all but the most basic questions.

Comment: I'll add the sources I used, and will change my verbiage to be more definitive. I would have done this already but I answered from my phone. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe just adding a source for the images may help a lot. For the moment, the only thing that could make us thing the scarring on the images are due to rain is  the title that you gave to the image.

Comment: @BryanKrause Proper edits have been made. Thanks again.

Comment: My cherries look quite similar with the rain affected ones that you linked. It's just that mine are darker and the cracks are wider. However, fruit diseases doesn't always make them rot, for example apple scab, sooty blotch and flyspeck - or avocado scab - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_scab - https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Avocado_scabs

Comment: @Fructibus In the case of cherries, most every disease [of cherry trees] either rots the cherry, or the fruit isn't affected at all. That being said, what may be true for apples [and other fruit] isn't necessarily true for cherries, and vise versa.